# React code changes randomly when going to any other app/site (changing tabs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, windows, visual-studio-code

I am learning react, and it has been going good until now. I have created a folder named 'reactpart', and i have started my react app there using

```
npx create-react app .
```

I made another folder called TodoList.js, and then rendered it inside App.js
App.js:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import TodoList from './TodoList'

function App() {
    return ( <
        TodoList / >

    )
}

export default App;
```

As you can see when I leave visual studio temporarily to look at the internet, or to go to any other site, the code becomes like this.

TodoList.js:

```
import React from 'react'

export default function TodoList() {
    return ( < div >

        Hello World

        <
        /div>
    )
}
```

When I look at the LocalHost however it is all normal:

[image]

It may be important to note that the react folder I am using **is inside another folder**, although **no files have the same name or code since I didn't write anything in the other one.**

As i have stated previously I use Visual Studio's latest version on Windows 10 Home.

Even if I change the code back to normal manually, it goes back to that weirdly shaped code whenever I change tabs.

I am not sure if this is from any snippet that I have downloaded, or Visual Studio, Javascript or React..

Comment: this has nothing to do with react please verify your VScode

Comment: To handle this problem you can use prettier code formatter or  ES7 + react code formatting extension. Set them as default.

Comment: Removed all the Visual Studio Extensions then installed the ones I need, and it worked! Thank you.